# Google maps get marker icon url on click

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I need to get marker icon url on click, I saw on google maps documentation that there is function getIcon() but don't know where to call it.

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function (kmlEvent) {
                    alert(kmlEvent.getIcon());//Object #<Object> has no method 'getIcon'
                    showInContentWindow(map, kmlEvent);
                });
```

**Update:**

```
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: null,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("kmlMapCanvas"), myOptions);

    var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(
    'https://maps.google.co.uk/maps/ms?msid=207817312541605896974.0004cdbf70e9c541de0ac&msa=0&ll=51.499019,-0.58382&spn=0.070103,0.209255&output=kml',
    {                       
      suppressInfoWindows: true,
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function (kmlEvent) {
             alert(kmlEvent.getIcon());//Object #<Object> has no method
        showInContentWindow(map, kmlEvent);
    });
```

where I am losing connection with native marker....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access the icon if you render your KML using KmlLayer.  If you use a third party parser, like [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/), which renders the KML using native Google Maps API v3 markers, you can access the icon, using the getIcon() method on the marker.

[Your KML displayed with geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.co.uk%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fmsid%3D207817312541605896974.0004cdbf70e9c541de0ac%26msa%3D0%26ll%3D51.499019%2C-0.58382%26spn%3D0.070103%2C0.209255%26output%3Dkml)

The urls of the icons are:

```
geoXmlDoc.placemarks[0].marker.getIcon().url
geoXmlDoc.placemarks[1].marker.getIcon().url
geoXmlDoc.placemarks[2].marker.getIcon().url
```

This works on that page (in the address bar, at least in IE):

```
javascript:alert(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[0].marker.getIcon().url);
```

Answer (score 1):

`getIcon()` is a method of `google.maps.Marker` . Placemarks(I guess that's what you click on), are rendered as markers, but are not native markers, so there is no method getIcon() you can use here.

There is no option inside the Maps-API to retrieve information about the rendered marker(Placemark).

Answer (score 1):

make sure `kmlEvent` is your marker, because `getIcon()` is a google.maps.Marker method

based on your comment

> how can I load/get native marker

this is how you add a marker to the map

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: userLatLngvariable,
    title: 'Your title here',
    draggable: true,
    map: map
});
```

see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/vA4eQ/
(click the "add marker" button)

Comment: o.k now marker.getIcon() is 'undefined' not getting it's url. Thanks for example.